# Stata: Delete all but one observations with the same value for a variable

Tags: duplicates, stata

I work with a dataset that looks like this:

```
    name   var1  ...
1    a       1       
2    a       1  
3    a       1  
4    a       2  
5    a       2  
6    a       3  
7    a       1  
8    a       1  
9    b       1    
10   b       1  
11   b       2  
12   b       2  
13   b       3  
14   b       3  
15   b       3
```

My problem is that I want to `drop` all observations with duplicated `name`/`var1` combinations, but only if the duplicates are adjacent (basically, I want to drop observation 2, 3, 5, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15).

My first thought was to create a while-loop and compare `var1` for observation i with `var1` for observation i+1 and then `drop` one of them if the values are equal, I just can't get it to work in Stata.

Is there an (easy) way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to `drop` observations identical to the previous on two variables:

```
drop if name == name[_n-1] & var1 == var1[_n-1]
```

Note that this is a loop, just a tacit loop, as Stata executes in observation order, comparing the 2nd observation with the 1st, and so on.

Comment: Ok, didn't know about tacit loops in stata. But it worked fine, thank you! :)